# PHP/CSV : how to echo an end of row?

Tags: php, csv, echo

I manually echo some data in a .csv file. For each row, I use the following code :

```
...(some data)."\n";
```

Now, I want to use a form where the user can input the end of row. For instance, if he wants his rows to be ended by "\n", he types : \n in the form.

My problem is how to handle this value in the PHP echo code ?

I've tried .$var, ."$var", I also tried to escape the double quotes, but I can't manage to reach my goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could instead make them type a character that they wouldn't use as content, for example `|` might work.

Then all you'd have to do is replace `|` by `\n` inside the string, you can do it this way:

```
$content = str_replace ('|','\n', $content);
```

Comment: Thanks !

`$fin = str_replace ("|n", "\n", $fin); `

works. But if I only want to replace the | into \, it doesn't work :

`$fin = str_replace ("|", "\\", $fin); `